# Angular ngFor - restriction to show on every item

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have got following code in my component.html. ( I am new to angular )

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of galleries;"
                 (mouseenter)=" setBackground(item?.image?.fullpath)"
                 (mouseover)="showCount = true; getImagesCount(item.path);" (mouseleave)="showCount = false">
                <img class="card-img-top" [routerLink]="['/'+item.path]"
                     [src]="item?.image?.fullpath ? path + '0x156/' + item?.image?.fullpath : defaultImage"
                     alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title imagesCount"></h4>
                    <h4 class="card-title title">{{item.name}}</h4>
                    <img class="closeIcon" src="../../../assets/images/close.png" alt="" (click)="removeGallery(item);">
                    <span class="animated fadeInUp" *ngIf="showCount">{{imagesCount}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Down in the code i have ***ngIf="showCount** where i am trying to show how many images gallery have. But issue is that it is shown on **every card**, but i want it to show only on current card that i enter my mouse with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create an extra key i.e. **showCount** inside item object.

```
item = {
...,
showCount: false
}
```

than use that key for showing and hiding showCount in the HTML.

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of galleries;"
       (mouseenter)=" setBackground(item?.image?.fullpath)"
       (mouseover)="item[showCount] = true; getImagesCount(item.path);"               
       (mouseleave)="item[showCount] = false">
                <img class="card-img-top" [routerLink]="['/'+item.path]"
                     [src]="item?.image?.fullpath ? path + '0x156/' + item?.image?.fullpath : defaultImage"
                     alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title imagesCount"></h4>
                    <h4 class="card-title title">{{item.name}}</h4>
                    <img class="closeIcon" src="../../../assets/images/close.png" alt="" (click)="removeGallery(item);">
                    <span class="animated fadeInUp" [hidden]="item[showCount]">{{imagesCount}}</span>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i create extra key in item object ? ngfor make this object

Comment: I am sure you have control over galleries. 
galleries.map(item => item['showCount'] = false). I hope it might help.

Comment: Interesting solution, and works well. PS: my thumb up is not displaying though.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify your `*ngIf` in:

```
<span class="animated fadeInUp" *ngIf="showCount">{{imagesCount}}</span>
```

because actually you will get for every item in your galleries list.

Here is an idea, how you can specify that:

**Step 1: Add new variable to your component.ts**

```
currentItem: number;
```

**Step 2: add index to your ngFor**

```
*ngFor="let item of galleries; let index = index;"
```

**Step 3: Extend your (mouseover) and (mouseleave) events**

Add `currentItem` and fill with data.

```
(mouseover)="showCount = true; currentItem = index; getImagesCount(item.path);" 
(mouseleave)="showCount = false; currentItem = null;"
```

**Step 4: Change you *ngIf in span with itemsCount**

```
<span class="animated fadeInUp" *ngIf="showCount && currentItem == index">{{imagesCount}}</span>
```

Now you have a spicified solution.

Comment: @uppermost If your question is answered and, please mark an answer. So that other users know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by making your 'showCount' variable into an array, and comparing *ngIf to the array value:

Some small tweaks:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of galleries; let idx=index">
    ....
    (mouseover)="showCount[idx]=true
    (mouseleave)="showCount[idx]=false
</div>

...
<span class="animated fadeInUp" *ngIf="showCount[idx]">
```